# Spring MVC application on JBOSS App Server

Tags: java, spring, jboss6.x

I am new to JBOSS application server. I am trying to create a simple application to see my first page on screen with JBOSS.
But I am finding an error like:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /DeploymentManagement/
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /DeploymentManagement/

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1
```

My AppConfig class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.optum.basics")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }}
```

My AppInitializer class is:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

My Controller class is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@ComponentScan("com.spring.basics") 
public class AppController {


    /*
     * This method will list all existing deployments.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/listNonClosedReqs" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listNonClosedDeployments(ModelMap model) {

                return "index";
    }}
```

Server logs which I found is:

```
 19:21:21,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found DeploymentManagement.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called DeploymentManagement.war.dodeploy
19:21:27,238 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "DeploymentManagement.war" (runtime-name: "DeploymentManagement.war")
19:21:32,630 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
19:21:32,631 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
19:21:32,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
19:21:32,812 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "DeploymentManagement.war" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
19:21:32,980 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS018210: Register web context: /DeploymentManagement
19:21:33,125 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/DeploymentManagement]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
19:21:34,073 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/DeploymentManagement]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
19:21:34,073 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
19:21:34,105 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Sep 01 19:21:34 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
19:21:34,269 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Registering annotated classes: [class com.optum.basics.config.AppConfig]
19:21:35,148 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
19:21:36,376 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
19:21:36,500 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
19:21:36,504 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
19:21:36,544 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
19:21:42,963 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
19:21:45,635 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000270: Type registration [byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@520513d8
19:21:45,635 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000270: Type registration [[B] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@520513d8
19:21:45,635 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000270: Type registration [Byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@7d3f713
19:21:45,635 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000270: Type registration [[Ljava.lang.Byte;] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@7d3f713
19:21:45,944 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final-redhat-2
19:21:49,698 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@2c8c0e7f] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
19:21:50,427 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Mapped "{[/ || /listNonClosedReqs],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.optum.basics.controller.AppController.listNonClosedDeployments(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
19:21:51,083 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Sep 01 19:21:34 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
19:21:51,594 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 17521 ms
19:21:52,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015859: Deployed "DeploymentManagement.war" (runtime-name : "DeploymentManagement.war")
```

Could any one of please help me to learn spring MVC on JBOSS?

Comment: Can you share the logs from the `server.log` file? It would contain logs indicating whether the deployment of the `.war` or `.ear` was successful or not.

Comment: Thank Aniket for your suggestion. I have gone through server log and resolved the issues which I can. At the end I got struck with the attached error log. Could you please help me on this issue?

Comment: There are issues with `DI` of `deploymentService`, `deploymentDao`, `sessionFactory` as shown by the logs. Please check your `spring-context.xml` and/or the `@Autowired` components in the individual classes.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
 This is a key error message I am finding. Not sure if this is the actual one

Comment: @Aniket: Now I resolved all the issues by placing correct version of jars and server log is also looking good (Updated server log in my post). But still I am seeing the same error when I run my application. Could you please throw any light on me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried changing your servlet mapping from "/" to "/*"?

Comment: @SeanCarroll: Yes I tried "/*" but dint get any luck

Comment: I wonder if this is also related to other stackoverflow question

Comment: yes it is same as the other one